# Extract text inside HTML tags using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I have an XML file that has some CDATA with html tags. Example:

```
<TextElement>
  <Data>
    <![CDATA[ <h2>My Header Text</h2> ]]>
  </Data>
</TextElement>
```

I need to be able to display "My Header Text" without the H2 tag.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that the content is a single `h2` element with pure text content and no child elements? And which XSLT 1 processor do you use?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this using xslt? Please add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, the content will always be a single h2 tag, no child elements. I'm using Xalan for my XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<xsl:param name="start-tag"><![CDATA[<h2>]]></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="end-tag"><![CDATA[</h2>]]></xsl:param>
```

and then a `substring-after(substring-before` combination

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., $start-tag), $end-tag)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should do. http://xsltransform.net/naZXpY6.